# Select join (select xxx) in django?

Tags: mysql, django

I would like to use Django ORM to code this SQL request :

```
SELECT * FROM versionning t1 
  JOIN (
      SELECT MAX( version ) AS version, name FROM versionning
      WHERE updated < '2011-11-15'
      GROUP BY name
       ) t2 
  ON t1.version = t2.version AND t1.name = t2.name
```

where the SQL table 'versionning' is :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `versionning` (
  `uuid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The Goal is to have versionning for objects. In my case, I want to be able to have several objects having the same name but with different version numbers. Then I want to select the latest version of all objects present on '2011-11-15'.

How can I do that by using Django ORM ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates

Answer (score 0):

Django supports raw SQL queries ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries ), so you can write something like this:

```
Versioning.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM versioning ...')
```

Comment: Yes, but by this way, I loose django ORM features (I want to use filtering too, so raw function is not a solution...)

Answer (score 0):

A great solution to your stated goal is to use [Django-Reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion).

From the link:

> **django-reversion** is an extension to the Django web framework that
> provides comprehensive version control facilities.
>
> ## Features
>
> - Roll back to any point in a model's history - an unlimited undo
>   facility!
> - Recover deleted models - never lose data again!
> - Admin integration for maximum usability.
> - Group related changes into
>   revisions that can be rolled back in a single transaction.
> - Automatically save a new version whenever your model changes using
>   Django's flexible signalling framework.
> - Automate your revision
>   management with easy-to-use middleware.
>
> **django-reversion** can be easily
> added to your existing Django project with an absolute minimum of code
> changes.

Comment: Unfortunately django-reversion is not able to make selection like my SQL request : you have to make a request for each object you are displaying.